# Hiding and Unhiding columns based on prompt

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a template that hides and unhides columns based the value in G2. When a user will value from 1-5 in G2, certain columns will be shown, and certain columns will be hidden. Specifically, I'm looking to show only columns 1-3 when G2 is "1", show only columns 1-6 when G2 is "2", show only columns 1-9 when G2 is "3" and so on.

[image: sample range]

Here's my attempt. It doesn't produce an error, but nothing happens when I run it.

```
function showColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var COLUMN = sheet.getRange('G2').getValue();
if (COLUMN=='1') {
  sheet.showColumns(1,3);  
  sheet.hideColumns(4,12);
  }
if (COLUMN=='2') {
  sheet.showColumns(1,6);  
  sheet.hideColumns(7,9);
  }
if (COLUMN=='3') {
  sheet.showColumns(1,9);  
  sheet.hideColumns(10,6);
  }
if (COLUMN=='4') {
  sheet.showColumns(1,12);  
  sheet.hideColumns(13,3);
  }
if (COLUMN=='5') {
  sheet.showColumns(1,15);   
  }

 }
```

I only have 5 sets of 3 columns, with the number of sets showing up depending on G2, hence why I tried the simplistic approach of showing/hiding specific rows depending on the input, although I'm positive there's an easier way to do this.
I greatly appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem is due that the code is comparing the value of `COLUMN` with `Strings` rather than `Numbers`, replace `'1'` by 1, `'2'` by `2`, and so on.

By the other hand it could be a good idea to use a `switch` statement of use `if..else if` instead of several independent `if`, also it could be a good idea to check that `G2` value has the correct data type.

Comment: Hi Ruben, your suggestion worked perfectly! It was solved when I replaced '1' with 1 and so on.